# Java Object construction in parts

Tags: java, builder, completable-future, abstract-factory

I have a complex object which comprises of several parts. Each part requires data to be fetched from a different service (REST call).

```
public class Resource {
     int quantity;            // Service 1
     String name;             // Service 2
     Price price;             // Service 2, 3
     ...
}

public class Price {
     double value;              // Service 2
     String currency;           // Service 2
     int discount_percentage;   // Service 3
}
```

I'm planning to use AbstractFactories and Java's CompletableFuture's to accomplish the same.

However, I'm unsure how I might be able to do this - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The example below is with builder and CompletableFuture instead of AbstractFactory but maybe helps

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CompletableFuture<ComplexObject> completableFuture = CompletableFuture
                                                    .supplyAsync(()-> ComplexObject.builder())
                                                    .thenApply(cob -> cob.withComplexProp1(restService1.getDetails()))
                                                    .thenApply(cob -> cob.withComplexProp2(restService2.getDetails()))
                                                    .thenApply(cob -> cob.withComplexPropN(restServiceN.getDetails()))
                                                    .thenApply(cob -> cob.build());
        try {
            ComplexObject co = completableFuture.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("could not build the complex object");
        }
    }


}


class ComplexObject {
    private Object complexProp1;
    private Object complexProp2;
    private Object complexPropN;

    private ComplexObject() {}

    public static ComplexObjectBuilder builder() {
        return new ComplexObjectBuilder();
    }

    public static class ComplexObjectBuilder {

        private Object complexProp1;
        private Object complexProp2;
        private Object complexPropN;

        private ComplexObjectBuilder() {

        }

        public ComplexObjectBuilder withComplexProp1(Object complexProp1) {
            // process the received complexProp1 before setting it into the builder
            this.complexProp1 = complexProp1;
            return this;
        }
        public ComplexObjectBuilder withComplexProp2(Object complexProp1) {
            // process the received complexProp2 before setting it into the builder
            this.complexProp2 = complexProp2;
            return this;
        }
        public ComplexObjectBuilder withComplexPropN(Object complexProp1) {
            // process the received complexPropN before setting it into the builder
            this.complexPropN = complexPropN;
            return this;
        }

        public ComplexObject build() {
            ComplexObject co = new ComplexObject();
            co.complexProp1 = this.complexProp1;
            co.complexProp2 = this.complexProp2;
            co.complexPropN = this.complexPropN;
            return co;
        }
    }
}
```